# Is a fixed point, which is attracting on a manifold $M$, always globally stable if $M$ is globally attracting?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Lets start with a toy example system of equations

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=x(1-x)-xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-y
\end{align}

I'd like to show $(1,0)$ has a basin of attraction that includes all of $B:=\{(x,y): 0<x<1, y\geq 0 \}$. The x-axis is obviously attracting on $B$, given $dy/dt=-y$. And on the x-axis, the point x=1 attracts all positive $x$. How can we prove that all trajectories with initial conditions in $B$ flow to $(1,0)$. And does this concept generalize to systems as follows?

The general question in 2D, given a dynamical system

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,y)\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y)
\end{align}

with a globally attracting curve $C:=\{(x,y): y=h(x)\}$, such that all points $(x,y)$ not on $C$ approach $C$. My question is, if there exists a unique fixed point $(x^*,y^*)$ on $C$ such that it attracts all points on the curve $C$, can we call that fixed point globally stable. Intuitively it seems like it has to be. I'm wondering if anyone has a proof for this proposition or a counterexample?

Comment: So, is your problem about constructing Lyapunov function for proving global stability or in proving global stability no matter what? Because you seem to be very focused on constructing precious analytic expression for Lyapunov function here. _Added later_: also, note that this equilibrium is not really globally attractive: there is a set of points (namely, stable manifold of saddle at the origin) that go to this saddle. And the whole left halfplane goes just to infinity.

Comment: @Evgeny I'm interested in proving "global" stability in general (not constructing a Lyapunov function per say), but what I really mean by global stability is that the basin of attraction of (1,0) contains the whole specified domain {(x,y) : 0<x<1, y≥0}

Comment: What is your precise definition of a globally attractive invariant curve $C$? This result depends on this definition.

Comment: @Futurologist For the general statement, for all x0 in B, you can find a t such that for any epsilon x(t) gets epsilon close to a point on C using euclidean distance. However, a discussion on the how much this definition matters would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the example, one need only choose the Lyapunov function

\begin{equation}
V(x,y)=y^2+(x+y-1)^2
\end{equation}

Clearly, $V(k,0)=0$ and $V(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)\neq(k,0)$ in $B$. Note

\begin{align}
\dot{V}(x,y)&=2y\dot{y}+2(x+y-1)\dot{x}+2(x+y-1)\dot{y}\\
\end{align}

Case (1) $x>y-1$: the first and third therm are always negative because $\dot{y}$ is negative. The second term is negative because $x>y-1$ only includes points above the $dx/dt$ nullcline and hence, $\dot{x}>0$.

Case (2) $x<y-1$: The second term is negative because $x<y-1$ means $(x+y-1)<0$ sincle it also means $(x,y)$ is below the $dx/dt$ nullcline and hence, $\dot{x}>0$. Note that the third term is positive. However because $|x+y-1|<y$, (note $0<x \leq 1$ required to be in $B$) it is less positive than the first term is negative.

Case (3) $x=y-1$: $\dot{V}=-2y^2<0$.

Therefore $(k,0)$ attracks all trajectories on $B$. Here I exploited the fact that trajectories always flow down to the x axis, and the fact that in the x direction they flow towards the $dx/dt$ nullcline, which is why I chose $[x-x_{nullcline}(y)]^2$ in the Lyapunov function.

Unfortunately I don't think you will always be able to exploit this, so it doesn't help with the general proposition, but it might provide some insight.

Answer (score 2):

If we have the right definitions, we can have a precise statement which is more or less what you need.

For simplicity let $z = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and denote by
$$X(z) = f(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + g(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial
y}$$ the vector field corresponding to the smooth (or real analytic
or polynomial) dynamical system
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x,y)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= g(x,y)
\end{align*}
which we will also write as
$$\dot{z} = X(z)$$
For simplicity, we denote by $o = (o_1,o_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the equilibrium
point of $X(z)$, i.e. $X(o) = 0$. Furthermore, by $\phi^t(z)$ we
define the phase flow of $X(z)$. That is $\phi^t(z)$ solves the
initial value problem

$$\frac{d}{dt} \, \phi^t(z) = X\big(\phi^t(z)\big)$$
$$\phi^0(z) = z$$

**Definition 1.** *Let $\gamma = \big\{(x,h(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\, | \,\, x \in [a,b]\, \big\}$ be a compact embedded smooth (or real analytic)
curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We call it **invariant curve of the vector field $X$** whenever*

*$\bullet$ $\gamma$ is invariant under the flow $\phi^t(z)$, i.e. if $z
\in \gamma$ then $\phi^t(z) \in \gamma$ for all $t\geq 0$, which
is true if and only if the vector field $X(z)$ is tangent to
$\gamma$ for each $z \in \gamma$ and points inwards at the endpoints of $\gamma$.*

**Definition 2.** *The invariant curve $\gamma$ of $X$ is called  **stable** whenever*

*$\bullet$ for any open set $U$ containing $\gamma$, there exists an open
set $V$ containing $\gamma$ such that if $z\in V$ then $\phi^t(z)
\in U$ for all $t\geq 0$. Clearly, $V \subseteq U$.*

**Definition 3.** *The invariant curve $\gamma$ of $X$ is called **attracting with basin of attraction $BA \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$** whenever*

*1. $\gamma$ is stable;*

*2. $\gamma \subset BA$, where $BA$ is an open subset of
$\mathbb{R}^2$;*

*3. For any open set $U$ containing $\gamma$ and any $z \in BA$
there exists $T\geq 0$ such that $\phi^t(z) \in U$ for any $t \geq
T$.*

*4. The open set $BA$ is the maximal open set with properties 1,
2, 3 above.*

Similar definitions apply to the point $o = (o_1,o_2) \in
\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Definition 4.** *The equilibrium point $o = (o_1,o_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ of
$X$ is called **stable** whenever*

*$\bullet$ for any open set $U$ containing $o$,  there exists an open set
$V$ containing $o$ such that if $z \in V$ then $\phi^t(z) \in U$
for all $t\geq 0$. Clearly, $V \subseteq U$.*

**Definition 5.** *The equilibrium point $o = (o_1,o_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ of
$X$ is called **attracting with basin of attraction $BA \subseteq
\mathbb{R}^2$** whenever*

*1. $o$ is stable;*

*2. $o \in BA$, where $BA$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$;*

*3. For any open set $U$ containing $o$ and any $z \in BA$ there
exists $T\geq 0$ such that $\phi^t(z) \in U$ for any $t \geq T$.*

*4. The open set $BA$ is the maximal open set with properties $1,
2, 3$ above.*

For both definition of attraction, we can show that, due to its
maximality, the basin of attraction $BA$ is an invariant open set for
the vector field $X$, i.e. $\phi^t(z) \in BA$ for any $z \in BA$
and $t \geq 0$.

**Theorem.** *Let $\gamma = \big\{(x,h(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\, |
\,\, x \in [a,b]\, \big\}$ be a smooth (or real analytic)
invariant (compact!) curve for the smooth (real analytic or
polynomial) dynamical system in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the vector
field $X(z)$ above.*

*1. Let $o = (o_1,o_2)$ be the only equilibrium point of $X(z)$
lying on $\gamma$;*

*2.  Let $\lim_{t \to \infty} \, \phi^t(z) = o$ for all $z \in
\gamma$.*

*3. Assume that the invariant curve $\gamma$ is attracting with
basin of attraction $BA \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ (open);*

*Then the equilibrium point $o$ is attracting
with basin of attraction $BA$ and hence (asymptotically) stable.*

Observe that in your example, the set $B$ is not a basin of attraction. It is not maximal. And the equilibrium point is handled only on one side of the invariant curve, while in general you should handle it from all sides (right and left up and down).

Comment: I don't know about OP's interest, but mine is of course about proof of this theorem :)

Comment: Also, it is kind of nitpicking, but for me it seems that there is a minor contradiction in your conditions. If this invariant curve is compact and it is  homeomorphic to unit segment, then its endpoints must be equilibria -- there's got to be something that prevents trajectory "to leak out" through boundary of this segment. So, you can't say that for all initial conditions on this invariant curve trajectories go to the equilibrium $o$. But I think that this might be fixable.

Comment: @Evgeny The invariant curve $\gamma$ is not assumed to be a maximal invariant manifold of the vector field $X$. Otherwise, you cannot really define it as a graph of $y=h(x)$ (e.g. homoclinic trajectory or heteroclinic connected to another equilibrium of type repelling sink). I have only chosen a compact portion of it around the equilibrium point $o$, where it can be written as $y=h(x)$. By assumption, the vector field $X$ restricted to $\gamma$ forms a one dimensional dynamical system with asymptotically stable equilibrium $o \in \gamma$, i.e. $\gamma$ is an invariant domain for $o$.

Comment: @Evgeny Basically the vector field $X$ restricted to $\gamma$ points always towards the equilibrium point $o$ (otherwise $o$ is unstable in two dimensional system $X$) so no leakage can occur. And that's why $\gamma$ is an invariant domain of $X |_{\gamma}$.

Comment: Okay, I've understood, you've used your terminology instead of already existing terminology and that confused me, sorry. There are already the notions of forward-invariant set and backward-invariant. What you've called _invariant_ here is really called forward-invariant. Btw, as far as I understood, OP's question is about forward and backward invariant curve that could be represented as graph.

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah, terminology varies a bit, sometimes it depends on who writes the article. Plus I wasn't very careful to follow established terminology as the OP is not following one either. OP never asked anything about backward invariant curve (because the interest in forward stability). As I said, a maximally invariant submanifold is not always a graph of a function globally. Actually, in some weird cases it might not be an embedded submanifold (just immersed). This is especially true for surfaces with more complicated topology than the plane, as the invariant curve can be dense.

Comment: @Evgeny Actually, I was a bit restrictive in the definition of invariant $\gamma$. In general an invariant curve $\gamma$ is a smooth curve such that $X$ is tangent to it, i.e. for each $z \in \gamma$ there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\phi^t(z) \in \gamma$ for all $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. But I don't use it in my arguments, so I skipped it.

Comment: Okay, let's leave the terminological issues. For me it's important: do you have the proof, or you've skipped it for some reasons?

Comment: @Evgeny I was also mostly interested in the proof